# The specified path, file name, or both are too long Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the below line in my powershell script in windows 7

```
$subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
```

The problem I get this error `The specified path, file name, or both are too long` in some of the files.

I looked into it and found some suggestions to add `\\?\` before the file path I tried as below and it's not working any advice?

```
$Base = '\\?\'
$subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $Base$i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
```

Comment: There is a 260 character limit for NTFS Paths. [This is a Microsoft limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). However, MS announced not too long ago that you can eliminate this limitation by editing the registry key `LongPathsEnabled` or enabling in group policy

Comment: what OS are you running one? win10 has a config option to enable long fie name support.

Comment: `$Base$i.FullName` --> `($Base + $i.FullName)`

Comment: @AdminOfThings nice catch

Comment: @AdminOfThings I tried this but I get this error ` Get-ChildItem : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.`

Comment: What is the result of `($Base + $i.FullName)`? Try `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath ($Base + $i.FullName)`

Comment: @Theo It gives the same error "Get-ChildItem : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again."

Comment: So, what **is** the result of ($Base + $i.FullName)?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -recurse $Base$i` works for me, assuming $i is `get-item something` (a DirectoryInfo object), which is not shown.

Comment: If the path is an UNC path, the prefix for a long path is different. See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7355dfef-4db7-4873-ba3c-1d8acefc6f86/syntax-for-long-path-support-with-uncs?forum=winserverfiles). You still haven't told us what the path looks like though. Do you want to get help?

Comment: @Theo  \\?\\\rackstation.mydom.com\main\sub.arch\mydom-customers\John_Marcus-123456 this is the result but then I get this error "Get-ChildItem : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again."

Comment: I don't suppose this is windows 10?  You can enable long filename support:  https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/enable-long-file-name-support-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have commented, the path in `$i.FullName` is in UNC format (`\\server\share\restofpath`).

In that case, the prefix for long path should be `\\?\UNC\` and the first two backslashes of the path itself need to be removed. In your case, it should be:
`\\?\UNC\rackstation.mydom.com\main\sub.arch\mydom-customers\John_Marcus-123456`

Using this prefix only works with the `-LiteralPath` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`.

Try

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath ('\\?\UNC\' + $i.FullName.Substring(2))
```

For things like this, I always keep a small helper function handy:

```
function Add-LongPathPrefix([string] $Path) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Path) -or $Path.StartsWith('\\?\')) {   #'# nothing to do here
        return $Path
    }
    if ($Path.StartsWith('\\')) {
        # it's a UNC path like \\server\share\restofpath
        return '\\?\UNC\' + $Path.Substring(2)   #'#  --> \\?\UNC\server\share\restofpath
    }
    else {
        # it's a local path like X:\restofpath
        return '\\?\' + $Path                    #'#  --> \\?\X:\restofpath
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Add-LongPathPrefix $i.FullName)
```

P.S. For this you need to have Powershell 5.1 or higher

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried both suggestions and in both I get this error " Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path." But when I remove the "?" it gives the other error again.

Comment: @Tak I think you are NOT specifying the `-LiteralPath` parameter. You cannot omit that. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: And how to specify `-LiteralPath`?

Comment: @Tak just exactly as i wrote it: `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Add-LongPathPrefix $i.FullName)`. If you simply do `Get-ChildItem (Add-LongPathPrefix $i.FullName)`, the cmdlet tries to use the path as the first positional parameter called `-Path`. Please look up the parameters and see the difference between `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#parameters)

Comment: I tried it but I still get this error `Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.`

Comment: and this is the output of  $PSVersionTable:                                                                                                                                                                                     
`PSVersion 3.0 - WSManStackVersion 3.0 - SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1 - CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000 - BuildVersion 6.2.9200.22198 - PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0, 3.0} - PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.2`

Comment: @Tak Ah, your Powershell version needs to be Powershell 5.1 minimum. Any chance you can update?